# How to call dotnet api from Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

This day is the first time for me to use dotNet web API for my project.
This is the code of my controller

```
public IEnumerable<Waybill> Get(string id_wb) {
    List<Waybill> lstWaybill = new List<Waybill>();
    lstWaybill = objway.GetWaybill(id_wb).ToList();
    return lstWaybill;
}
```

That API can work well if I'm call using this link :

```
http://localhost:56127/api/waybill/?id_wb=00000093
```

but I don't know how to call that link from my android app (I'm using retrofit)

```
@GET("Waybill/{id_wb}/id_wb")
Call<Waybill> getWaybillData(@Path("id_wb") String id_wb);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 options.

**First** one is to use Retrofit's `@Query` annotation.

```
@GET("Waybill/")
Call<Waybill> getWaybillData(@Query("id_wb") String id_wb);
```

The **second** one is to `@Path` annotation

```
@GET("Waybill/?id_wb={id_wb}")    // notice the difference in your code and my code
Call<Waybill> getWaybillData(@Path("id_wb") String id_wb);
```

The **third** option is to use `@Url` annotation. With this option, you need to prepare fully qualified URL before calling/using `getWaybillData()` method in your activity or fragment. Keep in mind that `@Url` method overrides base URL set in Retrofit client.

```
@GET    // notice the difference in your code and my code
Call<Waybill> getWaybillData(@Url String completeUrl);
```

If you follow 3rd option you need to prepare full URL in your activity like below.

```
String url = "http://<server_ip_address>:56127/api/waybill/?id_wb=00000093";
YourInterface api = ...
Call<Waybill> call = api.getWaybillData(url);
call.enqueue({/* implementation */});
```

I see a difference in the sample URL you mentioned and usage in Retrofit API interface.

In sample URL `waybill` is small and in API interface it is `Waybill`. Please ensure that you're using the right URL.